# xcode developer certificates and reset and reinstall

Tags: xcode, certificate

i installed xcode(6.3.1 beta) for unity ios app in Yosemite and was working fine when in upgrade to sierra and upgrade to xcode(8.1) xcode was not working and after checking in forms i found that it is OS issue i inatlled xlion .The problem i have another mac with Yosemite  and installed the xcode(6.3.1) and was messed up with key chain and other certificated for provision and distribution.Now i totally messed with xcode and distribution in developer account certificates and i was totally working with it for past two days and clueless what to do,How can i clear all developer certificates and key chain certificates from xcode like development and distribution i want to reset all things in xcode and developer account and start from starch and setup again everything .Please what are the things we needed to delete in the developer account and xcode and key chains and setup again to start as a new.

Comment: I am new to this form instead of support just putting negative us very bad this is my first post in this form i put my question in this form to get better respobse.please support me sonce i am new to this i will try to improvr in next question onwards

Answer (score 0):

Got to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/
then revoke you certificate..
[image]

[image]

then go to xcode. add a certificate to your project using your account xcode then will create certificate for you.... cheers...

[image]